# plot a function associated with some horizontal finite lines

Tags: plotting

I am going to plot the function `y[x_]:=1/x` associated with horizontal finite lines. For example at `y=-12,8, -6.5, -5.5, -5.0`. Can anyone help me to plot it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Show[{
  Plot[-(1/x), {x, 0.06, 1}, PlotRange -> {-13, 0.1}],
  Graphics[{Red, 
      Line[{{0, #}, {-(1/#), #}}]}] & /@ {-12, -8, -6.5, -5.5, -5.0}
  }]
```

yielding

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Following is the layman's way (Non-technical) to plot the required plot;

Here I am plotting each finite line from $0$ to intersection point of the line with the curve ($-1/x$). This intersection point (endpoint of the line) can be found by equating: $-1/x=-12 \rightarrow x=1/12$)

```
  y[x_] := -1/x
  p1 = Plot[{-12}, {x, 0, 1/12}] 
  p2 = Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 1}]
  Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can combine all the lines in a single plot.

```
   y[x_] := -1/x
   p1 = Table[Plot[{-1/n}, {x, 0, n}], {n, {1/12, 1/8, 1/6.5, 1/5.5,1/5}}];
   p2 = Plot[y[x], {x, 0.0, 1}]
   Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: finite lines!!! I think your lines are not finite.

Comment: @monfneg, Hey, I have modified.